# Can SQLAlchemy do a non-destructive alter of the db comparing the current model with db schema?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Basically I'm looking for an equivalent of DataMapper.auto_upgrade! from the Ruby world.

In other words:

1. change the model
2. *run some magic* -> current db schema is investigated and changed to reflect the model
3. profit

Of course, there are cases when it's impossible for such alteration to be non-desctructive, eg. when you deleted some attribute. But I don't mean such case. I'm looking for a general solution which doesn't get in the way when rapidly prototyping and changing the schema.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Sqlalchemy-migrate (http://packages.python.org/sqlalchemy-migrate/) is intended to help do these types of operations.

Comment: The problem with SQLAlchemy-migrate is that it introduces migrations (switching you from data mapper pattern to something more like active record pattern) and stores the metadata in its own format, so you're doomed to use this mechanism further. My point is it's not necessary as the metadata *is* already in the database and for several leading SQL backends it's easy to reach this info. It's what DataMapper does.    Also my point is not academic, the db schema will be changed by other parties and migrations are no-no.

Comment: I'm not crazy about sqlalchemy-migrate either for many reasons.  Besides yours it is a very leaky abstraction and it doesn't support MS SQL.  I can get most of the information I want via the MetaData and Inspector classes.  One gap I have at the moment is getting information about and creating views.  From Inspector you can walk the SQL for the view creation but I'd rather have the structure of the view exposed to me in a less raw manner.